# use boolean value for loop

Tags: java, for-loop

So technically a boolean is True (1) or False(0)...how can I use a boolean in a loop?

so if FYEProcessing is False, run this loop one time, if FYEProcessing is true, run it twice:

```
for (Integer i=0; i<FYEProcessing; ++i){
   CreatePaymentRecords(TermDates, FYEProcessing);      
}
```

Comment: As a side note, if you are looking for a boolean value inside of a loop, you can use `while` but it does not seem to work with what you need.

Comment: Nit: I think your "i<FYEProcessing" should be "i<=FYEProcessing" to represent the behavior you described.

Comment: You should also use int instead of Integer, although you never access the 'i' variable. Using Integer just adds overhead for no reason.

Comment: In Java there's no relationship between True and 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So technically a boolean is True (1) or False(0)

This is not true in Java. You cannot use an integer in place of a boolean expression in a conditional, i.e. `if (1) {...}` is not legal.

You are better of just doing this sequentially rather than attempting to use some sort of looping strategy to avoid having two lines which call `CreatePaymentRecords()`

```
CreatePaymentRecords(TermDates, FYEProcessing);  
if (FYEProcessing) {
    //run again
    CreatePaymentRecords(TermDates, FYEProcessing);  
}
```

Comment: thanks, that will work...with a little modification, I need the createPaymentRecords to enter a 0 the first time and a 1 the second time, so I'd have to hard code the values...

Answer (score 7):

```
for (int i=0; i < (FYEProcessing ? 2 : 1); ++i){
   CreatePaymentRecords(TermDates, FYEProcessing);      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a loop that would use a boolean true/false for the condition, just use `do {...} while (condition)` or `while (condition) {...}`. The first will always run at least once, then check the condition. The second would run only if the condition was initially true.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should strive to make code clearly understandable and I have hard time thinking where "boolean loop" is clear.  Trying to use a "boolean loop" may seem slicker in code, but I think it detracts from the understandability and maintainability of the code.

I distilled what you described:

> so if FYEProcessing is False, run this loop one time, if FYEProcessing is true, run it twice

into

> so if FYEProcessing is False, run this loop one time [with false], if FYEProcessing is true, run it twice [with false, then true]

or

> run this loop one time with false. If FYEProcessing is true, run it again with true

```
CreatePaymentRecords(TermDates, false);
if (FYEProcessing) {
    CreatePaymentRecords(TermDates, true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you simply want to execute this as long as the boolean is a particular value then use a do or while loop.

```
do { CreatePaymentRecords(TermDate, FYEProcessing); } while (FYEProcessing);
```

Comment: Unless CreatePaymentRecords updates the value of FYEProcessing (which we have not been told), then this loop will never exit.

Comment: given the question "how can I use a boolean in a loop?" my answer is informative.  Perhaps the author does know about do or while loops.  Using the if statement posted is not code most people would like to debug.